# Cannot resize taskbar icons anymore in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, taskbar, icons

Some Windows 11 updates reset taskbar icon size, truly annoying.

Before I managed to revert to small taskbar icons through registry, but now the latest update finally broke it completely, it does not work anymore.

I found [here](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/translucenttb-and-vivetool-fixes-for-taskbar-size-and-moment-3-features.13016/) something called vivetool but applying that solution did not work either.

Can you please suggest some other solution?

Comment: Is the RegEdit the 'TaskbarSi" method? Is this what doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Also have you seen [this](https://www.startallback.com/)?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid yes, `TaskbarSi` does not help anymore, neither `TaskbarSmallIcons` does. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it

Comment: @KalamalkaKid It surely worked, except it changed lots of other things too...

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Sure! Certainly I can customize it to meet my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The February 28th patch `KB5022913` broke the Taskbar Size tweak that many users were using as a [workaround](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/small-taskbar-icons.15514/) for the Windows 11 Taskbar issues.

Other users have found some success using TranslucentTB, and ViveTool. There is a thread about current issues you can read [HERE](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/translucenttb-and-vivetool-fixes-for-taskbar-size-and-moment-3-features.13016/). The thread started back in March of 2023, but has updated info as recent as June 2023.

Many users have reported success using [StartAllBack,](https://www.startallback.com/) to fix the taskbar icon size, however there are some side effects of using that which may affect other Windows visual layouts.

Comment: The second link in this post is currently redirecting to https://www.elevenforum.com/t/vivetool-and-how-to-use-it.13016/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Taskbar height and icon size](https://windhawk.net/mods/taskbar-icon-size) Windhawk mod.

First, download and install Windhawk from https://windhawk.net/. Then, go to "Mods" at the upper right, search for "Taskbar height and icon size" and install it.

Comment: It works perfectly and seems to be more stable than StartAllBack, but I find it inconvenient that windhawk must be running in the background all the time, otherwise modification becomes lost.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Ofc is must be running. You can just hide the tray icon in the app settings if it bothers.

Comment: Not working anymore (22631.3085) :(

Comment: Works for me @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ask the devs at https://github.com/ramensoftware/windhawk-mods/issues

Comment: Works now, after reinstalling Windhawk and installing fresh version of the mod, thank you